# Convert into proper XML format

Tags: c#, xml

i am getting an input string in the XML format but its symbols are in codes.
How can i convert the input in proper XML format using any function? 
or should i manually replace the codes with  symbols?

For example:

```
%3CUsers%3E
%3CUser%3E
%3CUserID%3E
567844d3-9ee8-463b-a1a0-9d7a8a59a66a
%3C/UserID%3E
%3CEmailID%3E
activation1@dealertrack.com
%3C/EmailID%3E
%3C/Users%3E
```

Convert this into

```
<Users>
<User>
<UserID>
567844d3-9ee8-463b-a1a0-9d7a8a59a66a
</UserID>
<EmailID>
activation1@site.com
</EmailID>
</Users>
```

PS: xml contains other symbols also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Web` and use the [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx):

```
var decodedXml = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

The data appears to be URL encoded.  You should be able to decode it by passing the whole string through:

```
string result = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(yourXmlString);
```

The `HttpUtility` class is in the `System.Web` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a once off thing, then a service such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ will sort you out. Otherwise use the [`HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) or [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx) methods

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stringToDecode)?
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help if it's a url decode/encode thing: [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx)
If its something else, please describe where you need it and why it is decoded this way.